# Why is Shannon crying to Mandy about Brian and Curt hooking up the night before?

Tags: plot-explanation, velvet-goldmine

The scene in *Velvet Goldmine* I am referring to comes after an orgy where everyone was "hooking up" with everyone. Women with women, men with men, etc. Shannon isn't even with Brian or Curt. So why is Shannon crying to Mandy about Brian and Curt hooking up the night before? If anyone would be upset, shouldn't it have been Mandy since she was married to Brian?